# How to make data persistent in Google Colab using Github or Google Drive?

Tags: git, github, google-colaboratory

I am using Git to clone my repository in Google Colab workspace then when I try to push changes to my repository, it tells me that access is denied. It doesn't even ask me for my username and password. I have been unsuccessful trying through SSH too.

May I know if there are any methods by which I can save the manipulated data processed in Google Colab for later use?

Answer (score 2):

If the remote repo URL is an https one, and Git does not ask you for credentials, check your credential helper:

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, on [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes), that would be `gcloud.cmd` or `gcloud.sh`.
That helper might have cached the wrong credentials (username/password)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/kaggle-on-google-colab-easiest-way-to-transfer-datasets-and-remote-bash-e54c64054faa). You can get access to full SSH terminal from Colab instance using Clouderizer. From there you can check in your code changes to git repositary as many times you wish.

Disclaimer: I am one of the creators of Clouderizer.